# Why do you despise me?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Why do you despise me based on my culture and kin?
Why hate my strategy of approaching the situations I'm in?
Cause you're just a fluffy pastry with sweet filling.

Do you hate that I'm sweet in my innermost being?
That I'm a medical miracle providing ultimate relieving?
But you pretend to have concern for those you're treating.

Do you know I support people, that some can't walk without me?
That I'm not the walls or the bars from which humans flee?
But you're unhealthy vanilla, red velvet, funfetti.

Why detest the flavorful words of a poet like myself?
Why spit them out so repulsed as if bad for your health?
Cause stripped from your banter you lie nakedly yourself.

Why do you despise me?
Why hate me so much?
Cause ...?

Hint:

> Each line has four
>  Each stanza has three
>  You'll know for sure
>  The connection you'll see

Comment: Regardless I am now hungry for some cake...

Comment: @indubitablee how am i supposed to respond?

Comment: @Parzival you're supposed to complete the last line by answering the question "why do you despise me"

Comment: On the contrary I don't despise you at all, and I think you have added some great posts to this community :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I see what you did there lol, thanks for the kind words

Comment: Okay I am ashamed to say it took me way too long to realize line 1 & 2 of each stanza is the call and line 3 is the response >.>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building off user1566694's answer:

> The words for each stanza end up as:
>  CLAN PLAN FLAN
>  CORE CURE CARE
>  CANE CAGE CAKE
>  BARD BARF BARE

If we then:

> Take the letter which changed in the final word of each row, you get:
>  F A K E

Why do you despise me?
Why hate me so much?
Cause ...?

> You're FAKE.

Answer (score 10):

I think I'm on the right track now...

---

Hint:

> Each line has four
>  Each stanza has three
>  You'll know for sure
>  The connection you'll see
>
>  **Letters** - Each line hints at a 4 letter word. Each stanza has 3 letters that differ in those words. And I think you even went as far as to make it the next letter in each set.

---

Why do you despise me based on my culture and kin?

> **C**LAN

Why hate my strategy of approaching the situations I'm in?

> **P**LAN

Cause you're just a fluffy pastry with sweet filling.

> **F**LAN

---

Do you hate that I'm sweet in my innermost being?

> C**O**RE

That I'm a medical miracle providing ultimate relieving?

> C**U**RE

But you pretend to have concern for those you're treating.

> C**A**RE

---

Do you know I support people, that some can't walk without me?

> CA**N**E

That I'm not the walls or the bars from which humans flee?

> CA**G**E

But you're unhealthy vanilla, red velvet, funfetti.

> CA**K**E

---

Why detest the flavorful words of a poet like myself?

> BAR**D**

Why spit them out so repulsed as if bad for your health?

> BAR**F**

Cause stripped from your banter you lie nakedly yourself.

> BAR**E**

---

Why do you despise me?
Why hate me so much?
Cause ...?

> Taking the 3 letters that differ from each stanza gives **CPFOUANGKDFE**, which is an anagram of ... absolutely nothing... and makes me hate you...

Comment: so close sir, +1

Comment: `and makes me hate you` awesome.

Comment: damn. someone beat me to it... i came back to change it to that...

Answer (score 2):

I hate you because I cant figure out how to make this fit as an answer:

> Confection

---

Why do you despise me based on my culture and kin?
Why hate my strategy of approaching the situations I'm in?
Cause you're just a fluffy pastry with sweet filling.

> 1. a sweet preparation of fruit or the like, as a preserve or candy.
>  2. the process of compounding, preparing, or making something.

Do you hate that I'm sweet in my innermost being?
That I'm a medical miracle providing ultimate relieving?
But you pretend to have concern for those you're treating.

> 6. Pharmacology. a medicated preparation made with the aid of sugar, honey, syrup, or the like.

Do you know I support people, that some can't walk without me?
That I'm not the walls or the bars from which humans flee?
But you're unhealthy vanilla, red velvet, funfetti.

> 3 types of cake and 2 lines I cant place.

Why detest the flavorful words of a poet like myself?
Why spit them out so repulsed as if bad for your health?
Cause stripped from your banter you lie nakedly yourself.

> 3. a frivolous, amusing, or contrived play, book, or other artistic or literary work.

---

Why do I hate you so much?

> I hate you because you're *Danish* and I'm Dutch.
>  I hate you because you're a *sugar pill*, sugar *cane*, a *cake*, a vice and a *crutch*.
>  I hate you cuz your words are all fluff.
>  I hate you cuz I'm fat now from all the things that you are that I can't get enough.

Comment: sweet answer, but unfortunately not on the right track

Comment: no? because i even added a rhyme..

Comment: haha +1 for that awesome rhyme and you earned more explanation: the riddle does not describe one thing. its a multi-step riddle, thats why you cant get any one answer to fit every line.

Comment: and as an added bonus for the use of "danish" which i find quite amusing: you're making some progress. if you figure out the hint and look at your rhyme, maybe something will click for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I despise you, because

> I would get hurt if I didn't.

Explanation:

> The riddle is refering to marijuana, and to "money" as the one it's calling out. Many industries would be [distrupted](http://extract.suntimes.com/extract-news/top-anti-marijuana-lobby-groups-united-states/) if marijuana was legalized, hence "money" gets hurt.

Cause you're just a fluffy pastry with sweet filling.
But you're unhealthy vanilla, red velvet, funfetti.

> These 2 lines refer to doughnut.

Cause stripped from your banter you lie nakedly yourself.

> When doughnut is stripped from its banter(its ingredients), what is left is just dough. Another meaning of the word "dough" is [money](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dough)

Why do you despise me based on my culture and kin?

> This refering to dangerous drugs, such as meth and cocaine. Altough marijuana is usually harmless, people judge it unfairly based on these drugs.

Do you hate that I'm sweet in my innermost being?

> Dough is not tasty by itself, but marijuana gets you high, without other ingredients.

That I'm a medical miracle providing ultimate relieving?

> Marijuana can be used for medical purposes, its most common use is to relieve the pain of cancer patients.

But you pretend to have concern for those you're treating.

> Could be a reference to market-based health insurance system in the United States. Money treats patients, but it doesn't care about patients at all. Its only concern is to take patients' money.

Do you know I support people, that some can't walk without me?

> Some patients can't even move because of their pain. They need marijuana to relieve this pain.

Why detest the flavorful words of a poet like myself?

> This can be clue for "dough"(flavorful words).

Why spit them out so repulsed as if bad for your health?

> Some people consider marijuana to be bad for health. They are so against it, they are repulsed by it. Even though it's actually harmless if not abused.

I am not sure about remaining lines.

Comment: o.o your answer has taken quite a turn haha. but sorry, this is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Total longshot!

Why do you despise me?
Why hate me so much?
Cause -

> I'm Dutch? (A Tom Pouce is a dutch pastry which rhymes handily)

Why do you despise me based on my culture and kin?
Why hate my strategy of approaching the situations I'm in?

> A Tom Pouce is a traditional desert commonly ridiculed for the difficulty in eating them

Cause you're just a fluffy pastry with sweet filling.

> A Tompouce has a fluffy, sweet cream filling

Do you hate that I'm sweet in my innermost being?
That I'm a medical miracle providing ultimate relieving?
But you pretend to have concern for those you're treating.

> The tompouce (or 'Tom Thumb') is named after an admiral who stopped growing in height at the age of 1 year.  A medical miracle?

Do you know I support people, that some can't walk without me?
That I'm not the walls or the bars from which humans flee?
But you're unhealthy vanilla, red velvet, funfetti.

> Flavors of tompouce bars/cakes?  or maybe a refference to the more generic Napoleon/vanilla slice?

Why detest the flavorful words of a poet like myself?
Why spit them out so repulsed as if bad for your health?
Cause stripped from your banter you lie nakedly yourself.

> no clue...

Comment: Your answer has taught me something new :] but sorry, it is not correct